# Make a weekly class schedule

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

The class schedule is defined as a array of struct Class.
It is necessary to write a function add_class which adds a new class to the schedule. The function should have a prototype:
`void add_class (struct Class schedule [], int number_of_classes, char * subject, int duration)`
This function should find the first free space in the schedule large enough for the required time and add a new member to the end of the schedule array. The *number_of_classes* indicates the number of members of the array, and the duration parameter is the desired hour duration in minutes. If there are no more vacancies in the function schedule, nothing needs to be done.

Also create one print function:
`void print_schedule (struct Class schedule [], int number_of_hours)`
which prints the schedule chronologically, arranged by days of the week and the time of the beginning of the class.

Assumptions and limitations:
Classes are held exclusively on weekdays in the period from 8:00 to 21:00.
The array in which the schedule is located does not have to be arranged chronologically, which means that e.g. the hour scheduled for Wednesday may be in a row before or after the hour scheduled for Tuesday, or the hour scheduled for 12h before the hour scheduled for the same day at 10h. The *print_schedule* function must print the schedule chronologically, not in the order in which the hours are arranged.

The *add_class* function should add the hour to the chronologically first available term. Eg if a class lasting 120 minutes is required and no other class is scheduled for Monday between 8:00 and 10:00, then the class should be set in that period. However, the Class element formed in this way should be placed at the end of the array, ie. to the first free spot in a row!

EXAMPLE:

```
MONDAY:   
08:00 - 9:40 Subject 1
09:40 - 13:00 Subject 2
13:00 - 14:40 Subject 3
14:40 - 19:40 Subject 4
TUESDAY:
08:00 - 16:20 Subject 5
16:20 - 19:40 Subject 7
WEDNESDAY:
08:00 - 18:00 Subject 6
18:00 - 19:40 Subject 8
THURSDAY:
08:00 - 14:40 Subject 9
14:40 - 19:40 Subject 10
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Time {
  int hour, minute;
} start, end;
struct Class {
  char subject[100];
  enum {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
  } day_of_week;
  struct Time start, end;
} schedule[100];
int add=0;
void print_day(int day) {
  switch (day) {
  case 0:
    printf("MONDAY:\n");
    break;
  case 1:
    printf("TUESDAY:\n");
    break;
  case 2:
    printf("WEDNESDAY:\n");
    break;
  case 3:
    printf("THURSDAY:\n");
    break;
  case 4:
    printf("FRIDAY:\n");
    break;
  default:
    printf("WRONG\n");
  }
}

void add_class(struct Class schedule[], int number_of_classes, char *subject,
               int duration) {
                   add=duration;
  int time_in_minutes;
  strcpy(schedule[number_of_classes].subject, subject); 
  schedule[0].start.hour = 8;
  schedule[0].start.minute = 0;
  if (number_of_classes == 0) {
    time_in_minutes = (schedule->start.hour) * 60 + schedule->start.minute + duration;
    schedule->end.hour = (int)(time_in_minutes / 60);
    schedule->end.minute = time_in_minutes - (schedule->end.hour) * 60;
  }
  else {
    int previous = number_of_classes - 1;
    schedule[number_of_classes].start.hour = schedule[previous].end.hour;
    schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute = schedule[previous].end.minute;
    time_in_minutes = (schedule[number_of_classes].start.hour) * 60 +
                      schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute + duration;
                      int temp=number_of_classes+1;
                      int temp_time_in_minutes=time_in_minutes;
                      if(temp_time_in_minutes>1260){
                          while(temp_time_in_minutes>1260){
        temp++;
        temp_time_in_minutes=(schedule[temp].start.hour) * 60 +
                      schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute + duration;
    }
    time_in_minutes=temp_time_in_minutes;
    schedule[number_of_classes].start.hour=8; 
    schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute=0;
 schedule[number_of_classes].end.hour=(int)(((schedule[number_of_classes].start.hour) * 60 +
                        schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute + duration)/60); 
    schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute= ((schedule[number_of_classes].start.hour) * 60 +
                        schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute + duration) - (schedule[number_of_classes].end.hour) * 60;
                      }

    if (time_in_minutes > 1260) {
      schedule[number_of_classes].start.hour = 8;
      schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute = 0;
      time_in_minutes = (schedule[number_of_classes].start.hour) * 60 +
                        schedule[number_of_classes].start.minute + duration;
    }
    schedule[number_of_classes].end.hour = (int)(time_in_minutes / 60);
    schedule[number_of_classes].end.minute = time_in_minutes - (schedule[number_of_classes].end.hour) * 60;
  }
}

void print_schedule(struct Class schedule[], int number_of_classes) {
  int i;
  int day_printed = 0;
  schedule[0].day_of_week = 0;
  schedule[1].day_of_week = 1;
  schedule[2].day_of_week = 2;
  schedule[3].day_of_week = 3;
  schedule[4].day_of_week = 4;
  int day=0;
  for (i = 0; i < number_of_classes; i++) {
   if(day_printed==0) print_day(schedule[day].day_of_week);
    if (schedule[i].start.hour > 9) printf("%d:", schedule[i].start.hour);
    else printf("0%d:", schedule[i].start.hour);
    if (schedule[i].start.minute > 9) printf("%d - ", schedule[i].start.minute);
    else printf("0%d - ", schedule[i].start.minute);
    if (schedule[i].end.hour > 9) printf("%d:", schedule[i].end.hour);
    else printf("0%d:", schedule[i].end.hour);
    if (schedule[i].end.minute > 9) printf("%d ", schedule[i].end.minute);
    else printf("0%d ", schedule[i].end.minute);
    int time_in_minutes = (schedule[i].end.hour) * 60 +
                      schedule[i].end.minute + add;
    printf("%s\n", schedule[i].subject);
    day_printed++; 
    if(time_in_minutes>1260){
        day++;
        day_printed=0;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int duration_arr[10] = {100,200,100,300,500,600,200,100,400,300};
     char subject_arr[10][15] = {"Subject 1","Subject 2","Subject 3","Subject 4",
     "Subject 5","Subject 6","Subject 7","Subject 8","Subject 9","Subject 10"};
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
         add_class(schedule,i,subject_arr[i],duration_arr[i]);
     }
     print_schedule(schedule,10);
  return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
MONDAY:
08:00 - 09:40 Subject 1
09:40 - 13:00 Subject 2
13:00 - 14:40 Subject 3
14:40 - 19:40 Subject 4
TUESDAY:
08:20 - 09:00 Subject 5
09:00 - 19:00 Subject 6
WEDNESDAY:
08:20 - 03:20 Subject 7
03:20 - 05:00 Subject 8
05:00 - 11:40 Subject 9
11:40 - 16:40 Subject 10
```

- I tried to check at first can class fit in term and if it can, it should be added, but this doesn't work.

Could you help me to modify this code to add classes to first free term (like in the example)?

Comment: `strcpy(schedule->subject, subject)`?

Comment: Or if you really want to have `schedule->subject=subject;` then change the struct field from `char subject[100];` to `char *subject;`

Comment: thanks, what about chronological order?

Comment: Use `qsort` to sort the array based on day, time and subject.

Comment: could you post answer as example of sorting based on day time and subject using qsort?